# Detached Thread: Handler not showing the Printfs

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm trying to compile and run the following code using `Detached Threads` in `C Linux`. The thing is that I want every thread to show me the corresponding `printf` from the handler `*idThreadMethod` and it doesn't show me anything! I tried using a `printf` before calling the `pthread_create` function and it shows it, but the problem should be inside the `*idThreadMethod` (handler function). The code:

```
//gcc detachedThreads.c -lpthread -o p
//./p 4

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int i;

void *idThreadMethod(void *args)
{
    int pid;

    pid = *((int *)args);

    printf("\nI'm The Detached Thread %d\n", i);
    printf("\nMy PID is: %d\n", pid);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int quantityThreads, returnThread, pid;
    pthread_t idThread[15];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    if(argc-1 < 1)
    {
        printf("\nSome arguments are missing\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    quantityThreads = atoi(argv[1]);

    pid=getpid();
    int *it = &pid;

    for(i=0;i<quantityThreads;i++)
    {
        returnThread = pthread_create(&idThread[i],&attr,idThreadMethod,it);

        if(returnThread == -1)
        {
            printf("\nThere is an error trying to create the thread\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What could I do in order to show the `printf` messages from the `*idThreadMethod` function?

Answer (score 2):

In main, use `pthread_exit`.  Your `main` is exiting and thus the rest of your threads die, detached or not.

Answer (score 1):

They're not showing because your main thread is exiting before they even get a chance to `printf`. As your threads are detached, you cannot use `pthread_join` to wait for them to do their thing, so you'll need some other form of synchronisation.

Seems to me, you don't really want detached threads at all....